# How to Replicate XMLHttpRequest For JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, xmlhttprequest, external

New to JSON, just trying to get my feet wet.

I know how to do this with XML via javascript, but am trying to learn how to handle JSON objects so I can switch over.

Basically I want to search through all "permalink" tags in the following JSON object and, when I find the right one, save its corresponding "title" and "id" tags to javascript variables:
http://api.soundcloud.com/users/goldenstatewarriors/tracks.json?client_id=02db8e29aa2fb5bf590f478b73137c67

Can this be done with only javascript (no PHP)? The main issue I'm facing is simply grabbing the text from the page and converting it to a json object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a JSON parser in order to transform the JSON string into an object you can handle natively in JavaScript. Recent browsers have this functionality built in as JSON.parse(), but obviously this will not work in older browsers (we're talking very old browsers here).

A solution to that problem is to use the JSON parsing library available [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js). If native browser support is detected, it simply uses that, otherwise it has a JavaScript implementation to achieve the same result. The file you'll need is json2.js - simply include that as you would any other library and away you go!

An example of the code would be:

```
var dataObject = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

As a side note, XMLHttpRequest is somewhat of a misnomer these days. It is simply a mechanism for making HTTP requests and retrieving the data returned, it doesn't have to be XML. It can be plain text, (non X)HTML, JSON, anything. In fact, I don't think I've seen anything in the wild return actual XML data for an XMLHttpRequest in a *very* long time.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This makes sense however I'm still unsure as to how to get the jsonData from an external site (in my case SoundCloud)

Comment: Ahh so per your edit I can use an HttpRequest to simply get the JSON text?

Comment: I amended my answer - essentially XHR requests don't need to return XML. One problem you will have is the Same Origin Policy. Basically this means you can't make requests to different domains without some foolery. A quick search on StackOverflow and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing should give you more information on that. Alternatively, you could use a server-side script to act as an intermediary between your site and SoundCloud.

Comment: Is there really no sample code out there for getting external json and parsing it with javascript? I can find examples for other languages but am limited to using js :/

Comment: The code is perfectly straightforward (the stuff in the answer works fine) but since it will be cross-domain, it may be a bit more difficult. I really recommend reading up on the topic, it is possible but you just need to configure things a little first.